# Spark how to use a UDF with a Join

Tags: apache-spark, join, dataframe, user-defined-functions

I'd like to use a specific `UDF` with using `Spark`

Here's the plan:

I have a `table A`(10 million rows) and a `table B`(15 millions rows)

I'd like to use an `UDF` comparing one element of the `table A` and one of the `table B`
Is it possible

Here's a a sample of my code. At some point i also need to say that my `UDF` compare must be greater than `0,9`:

```
DataFrame dfr = df
                .select("name", "firstname", "adress1", "city1","compare(adress1,adress2)")
                .join(dfa,df.col("adress1").equalTo(dfa.col("adress2"))
                        .and((df.col("city1").equalTo(dfa.col("city2"))
                                ...;
```

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. However it will be slower than normal operators, as Spark will be not able to do predicate pushdown

Example:

```
val udf = udf((x : String, y : String) => { here compute similarity; });
val df3 = df1.join(df2, udf(df1.field1, df2.field1) > 0.9)
```

For example:

```
val df1 = Seq (1, 2, 3, 4).toDF("x")
val df2 = Seq(1, 3, 7, 11).toDF("q")
val udf = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf((x : Int, q : Int) => { Math.abs(x - q); });
val df3 = df1.join(df2, udf(df1("x"), df2("q")) > 1)
```

You can also directly return boolean from User Defined Function

Comment: Any caching or other technique to make it a little faster?

Comment: @Samhash Caching makes sense if you read the data i.e. twice or even more often; if you dont' reuse the data, then I wouldn't recommend caching. UDFs are blackboxes, there is a ticket to create bytecode analyzer to speed them up, but it has low priority

Comment: I have read about broadcasting the smaller dataframe to all the nodes. It could be helpful.